# To_number function in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

```
TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('1234567891123.12',',','.'),'9999999999999999999999999D99')
```

returns `123456789112312`

How can i return `1234567891123.12`?

In oracle it was:

```
TO_NUMBER
(REPLACE('1234567891123.12',',','.')
9999999999999999999999999D99'
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
```

Comment: Your probably need to set `LC_NUMERIC` to change the decimal separator

Comment: If you always replace `,` with `.` you can also use the format mask `9999999999999999999999999.99`, or simply: `REPLACE('1234567891123.12',',','.')::numeric`